# add text in a button with image? objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

how would you write some text in a UIButton that already contains an image? i'd like to have a button like "save", but i also have an image that is the "button", so i put a UIButton on the view in IB, then either text first or image first, the text never shows up in front of the image. How would you do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UILabel` with the text you need, then add it as a subview to your `UIButton`. You can do that programmatically in the `-viewDidLoad` function of the view containing your `UIButton`s.

Comment: thanks , can't you do that directly in the IB? check this tut : http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/ it seems that they create the button directly from IB

Comment: You can create the button in IB and add the label in `-viewDidLoad` of the main view. I don't know of a way to add the label inside of the UIButton in IB (but you can try and place it above the UIButton if you are not fine with defining it programmatically, it might work for you).

Comment: alright, can you help me a little bit? i have created the outlet for the label : IBOutlet UILabel *save; and i already have a method for the button : - (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender; how can i call "this" button (sender) and tell him his subview will be the label?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand, but I guess what you are after is: `[(UIView*)id addSubview:save]`. You can call it from your `scheduleAlarm` and it will add the label as a subview to the sender.